# Can't get body onload work

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Im trying do display my body onload in a div tag, but cant solve it ? Can It be because I have 3 function in my javascript ?

When Im using a simple form, it works like a charm. But I dont want the form, just it to be displayed in a Div tag.

Thanks for al the help youre giving me here :)

this is my script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
// Get the HTTP Object
function getHTTPObject(){
   if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
      return null;

   }
}    
// Change the value of the outputText field
function setOutput(){
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('outputText').value = httpObject.responseText;
    }

} 
// Implement business logic    
function doWork(){    
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        httpObject.open("GET", "rss.php?rssFeed="
                        +document.getElementById('inputText').value, true);
        httpObject.send(null); 
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }

}

var httpObject = null;

//-->

</script>
```

This is the code im using for displaying.

The thing is that I do not want to use input type or textarea. since i get a border around the displaying text.

I just want it to look like plain text. not textfields.

```
<body onload="doWork()">
<div id="page-wrap">
<h1> Dagens ordspråk</h1>

<div id="myDiv">
<input type="hidden"  onclick="doWork();" name="inputText" id="inputText"/> 
<textarea name="outputText" id="outputText" cols="50" rows="20"></
</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you display the code that actually invokes one of your JS functions (for example, maybe you have `<body onload"doWork()">`)?

Comment: Sorry I cant,
Been trying with <body onload"doWork()"> But i wont show up.
Is there another way to display it in a div tag ?

Comment: Hey actually its working when im having <body onload"doWork()">

But its still works only with my form.
not only in the div tag.

Comment: The script you posted seems to have no relation to the question you are asking.  You posted 3 functions that perform an ajax request, but you asked about putting something in a div during body onload.  Please clarify your question, or show the code you are trying to use to put your "body onload in a div tag".

Comment: Im editing my question and pasting the code that Im trying to use that will display in my div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById('outputText').value = httpObject.responseText;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('outputText').innerHTML= httpObject.responseText;
```

And you can convert your textarea to a `div` to hold the results now..

```
<div id="outputText"></div>
```

---

Alternatively you can style the textarea and input to not have a border..

```
<style type="text/css">
   textarea{ border: 0;}
</style>
```